# Button blinking after click command is executed

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, button, wpf-controls

I am having weird problem. I have a form with a button. I set the background color of the button as `Blue` and it looks like the below image.

[image]

When I move over my mouse on it, it turns to light blue.

[image]

Now I press my left mouse button down and without leaving the button, drag my mouse outside the boundaries of the button and then leave the mouse click. Then the button starts blinking and changes color between these 2 images and never stops until I click any other control. Also, I have a command attached to this control. If I click this control then the command executes and again the button starts blinking between these 2 images and never stops until I click any other control like textbox, checkbox or something else. Can anyone help me to understand this.

Below is the `XAML for the button.

```
    <Button x:Name="BtnConvert" Content="Start Conversion Process" 
            Margin="0,436,433,0" 
            Height="108" Command="{Binding StartConvertProcess}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Width="236" FontSize="14" Background="#FF5998B6"/>
```

**Edit**

ViewModel Code

```
    private void StartConvertProcessMethod()
    {
        string errorMessage;
        bool result = _model.ConvertFiles(SourcePath, TargetPath, DataSource, out errorMessage);

        string caption;
        MessageBoxIcon messageBoxIcon;

        if (result)
        {
            caption = "Completed";
            messageBoxIcon = MessageBoxIcon.None;
        }
        else
        {
            caption = "Completed with Errors";
            messageBoxIcon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, messageBoxIcon);
    }
```

Comment: `IsConvertButtonEnable` was just an experiment to remove this effect. Sorry to include that in presented XAML. Let me remove it.

Comment: Please see edit...Do you need model code as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by defining ControlTemplate for my buttons. Something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="PlainButtonTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="bdr_main" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" CornerRadius="6"  Background="Transparent">
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" ContentSource="Content" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Apply the template to your button then.

```
<Style x:Key="PlainButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        ...
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource PlainButtonTemplate}"></Setter>
        ...
</Style>
```

Put the template and the style in a separate ResourceDictionary for example and then reference the dictionary in the pages, where you use buttons:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dict" Source="ResourceDictionaries\ButtonsDictionary.xaml" />                
 </ResourceDictionary>        
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am dead newbie. Can you elaborate a bit, where this code should be placed? I mean inside `Grid` tag or the `Button` tag? I am facing errors in either case....

Comment: Well..this solution is working. But may I get my default mouseover effect back along with this `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: Just edit the trigger for "IsMouseOver" event. Set the value in the Setter for any color you want instead of "Transparent" or define a LinearGradientBrush and apply it as a StaticResource (<Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SomeGradientBrush}"/>)